# GMod - lua code doesn't seem to work but displays no errors

Tags: lua, garrys-mod

Trying to change damage modifier in Garry's Mod with lua, because sk_npc_head doesn't work.
Here's the code I'm trying to use in Hammer Editor:

```
function FScaleNPCDamage( npc, hitgroup, dmginfo ) if ( hitgroup == HITGROUP_HEAD ) then dmginfo:ScaleDamage( 60 ) end end
```

Comment: that's just a syntactically correct function definiton. so if something is not behaving like you expect it either your expectations are wrong or you're using the function incorrectly. provide more code.

Answer (score 0):

Example from the [manual](https://wiki.facepunch.com/gmod/GM:ScaleNPCDamage):

> ```
> hook.Add( "ScaleNPCDamage", "ScaleNPCDamageExample", function( npc, hitgroup, dmginfo )
>   dmginfo:ScaleDamage( 2 )
> end )
> ```

So your code should look something like

```
hook.Add("ScaleNPCDamage", "YourFancyNPCDamageHook", function (npc, hitgroup, dmginfo)
  if hitgroup == HITGROUP_HEAD then
    dmginfo:ScaleDamage(60)
  end
end)
```

Comment: as I said, share your code. it is unlikely that code examples from the manual are incorrect

Comment: I've fixed this by changing " to ' :)